# Wrong spline length with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

With Get Spline Length i get wrong measurments for curly spline.
How to get proper length?

[image: wrong spline length]
Animation Nodes 2.0.4 Blender 2.79b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Get Spline Length* node approximates the length of the spline, as there is no efficient analytical solution to that. The node provides a *resolution* option in the *Advanced Node Settings* to control the precision of the approximation. Increasing that should allow a more accurate computation of the length:

[image: Option]

Comment: One little question off topic: Do You have AN on Blender 2.8?

Comment: @fomaamof Yes, it is not fully functional yet, but it is usable. However, there are no pre-compiled binaries available online, so you will have to compile it yourself if you want.